# Appended extra Escape character in string in c#

Tags: c#, string, app-config

I have added key in Appsetting of config file and I am trying to read this key.

```
<appSettings>
        <add key="fileNameReg" value="(?&lt;=filename\=\&quot;&quot;)(.*?)(?=\&quot;&quot;)" />
    </appSettings>
```

below the C# code in which i am trying to read.

```
string strConfig= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.["fileNameReg"];
```

I will get variable **strConfig** value below .

```
strConfig="(?<=filename\\=\\\"\")(.*?)(?=\\\"\")"
```

In this string, '\' is converted '\\' and " is converted in \" . How I can Get original value back?

Comment: Are you looking at the strings in the debugger?

Comment: \ is simply the escape character. The regex should still work fine.